# Ошибка CORS Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: javascript, запрос, get, apache2, cors

Столкнулся с очень навязчивой ошибкой CORS при выполнении межсерверного GET запроса из JS скрипта на свой сервер Apache с развернутым Django проектом. Самое интересное, что POST запрос на регистрацию отрабатывает без проблем. Я отправляю POST с регистрацией пользователя, затем отправляю POST с авторизацией для получения токена, а затем отправляю GET с токеном в Header для получения данных и каждый раз ловлю ошибку на этом этапе. Ошибка имеет следующий текст:

**Access to fetch at 'https://server.domain/accounts/all-profiles' from origin 'https://client.domain' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

3 дня я путешествовал по интернету, пробуя различные варианты решения этой проблемы, но положительного результата так и не получил. По-этому очень прошу помощи в этом вопросе. Через Postman запросы отлично работают.

**В файл конфигурации Apache **apache2.conf** добавлял разрешения**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
"append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization"
</IfModule>
```

**Добавлял редирект для проверочного запроса OPTIONS**

```
RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blank.html [QSA,L]
```

**Еще такой вариант пробовал**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

**Установил SSL для сервера**

**Установил SSL для клиента**

**Писал GET запрос и через XMLHttpRequest() и через fetch()**

Ниже мой JS запрос XMLHttpRequest()

```
const loginrequests = new XMLHttpRequest();
const CheckJWT = 'https://server.domain/accounts/all-profiles'

function ShowToken() {
    NewTok = localStorage.getItem("SavedToken");
    console.log(NewTok);
    loginrequests.open("GET", registerURL, true);
    loginrequests.setRequestHeader("Authorization", NewTok);
    loginrequests.send();

 }
```

Ниже мой JS запрос Fetch()

```
async function postData() {
NewTok = localStorage.getItem("SavedToken");
const CheckJWT = 'https://server.domain/accounts/all-profiles'

const response = await fetch(CheckJWT, {
method: 'GET', 
headers: {
  'Authorization': NewTok,
  },
});
return await response.json();
}
```

Еще ниже главное из моего файла конфигурации Apache **apache2.conf**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
</Directory>

WSGIPassAuthorization On

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers 
"append,delete,entries,foreach,get,has,keys,set,values,Authorization"
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On                  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blank.html [QSA,L]
```

Помогите пожалуйста, так как больше нет сил бросать горохом об стену, пробуя варианты, которые не помогают =.(

Answer (score 0):

Моя проблема заключалась в том, что Django не обрбатывал запросы OPTIONS. Проблема была решена при помощи данного модуля https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/